# Windows Domain-joined PC cannot RDP to a PC on another domain

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop

I created an AD DS and domain called NEWDOM. Then I added a Win2012 machine "newPC" with a local account called "userA" and joined it to the NEWDOM domain.

If I use my personal PC on home network, I can RDP to the machine without issue by providing "userA" or "newPC\userA" as username.

But if I use my company provided laptop, joined to COMPANYDOM but still connected to my home network, it refuses the credentials.  Audit logs on newPC show that it's attempting to use COMPANYDOM instead of newPC.  The XML says "TargetDomainName" is COMPANYDOM.  I've tried userA, newPC\userA, and userA@newPC and all give the same credentials error.

If I don't join newPC to the NEWDOM domain, it connects to RDP, even if on my company's network.  If I drop the machine from the NEWDOM domain, the issue persists.  Leads me to believe it's a GPO setting on the NEWDOM DC that's causing that but I'm not positive.

Is there a policy setting on my company laptop that is causing this or a setting on the NEWDOM domain controller?

Edit:  If I use a NEWDOM domain admin account, RDP works.  Only local accounts seem to have problems.  For reasons that I don't need to get into, I need the ability to RDP as local user accounts.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Issue appears to be that the work PC has the following key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\LmCompatibilityLevel=1 which restricts NTLM to version 1, which Windows Server 2012 does not support.

Comment: Yes, it is in the groups Users, Administrators, and Remote Desktop Users.   It is not the default Administrator account but rather an account I created locally on the machine prior to joining the domain.

If I try to RDP from a machine not on COMPANYDOM, it works fine.  It's only when I try to connect from my COMPANYDOM-joined laptop.

Comment: Sorry yes, you did explain it correctly. Maybe the firewall is set to only allow RDP connections within your company subnet?

Comment: I have a Domain Admin account set up on NEWDOM.  If I use the COMPANYDOM machine to RDP in, and I provide that NEWDOM domain admin account rather than local admin account, it connects without issue.

Comment: What if you logon as .\usera ? What version of RDP are you using?

Comment: On the Win 7 COMPANYDOM machine, it's 6.2.9200 and supports RDP 8.0 and NLA.   
On my personal win10 desktop, it's 10.0.10586 and supports RDP 10.0 and NLA.

Comment: Tried .\userA with the same results as "\userA", "NEWDOM\userA" and "userA@NEWDOM".

Comment: One thing I did just notice is that when a non-COMPANYDOM machine logs in successfully, it was using Negotiate auth.  When the COMPANYDOM machines fail, they're trying to use NTLM.  That might be the issue but not sure how to correct it.

Comment: Here is the audit info for a working login:  http://pastebin.com/wFRBWYHM
And here it is for a non-working login:  http://pastebin.com/3e3TLymf

Comment: Strange alright, I saw a few forum posts relating to NTLM issues from Windows 7 to Server 2012, do you have the following key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\LmCompatibilityLevel ?

Comment: newPC does not have that key defined.  Some possibly relevant keys defined in LSA:   NoLmHash=1, Authentication Packages=msv1_0, Security Packages="", usemachineid=1.

Comment: On the posts I saw it was actually the key on the client and deleting it seemed to fix the issue. Obviously as it's a work computer that may not be possible. This seems similar - [link]https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/case-of-the-logon-attempt-failed-rdp-connection/[/link].

Comment: Yes, lmcompatibilitylevel=1 on my COMPANYDOM laptop.

Comment: Server 2012 uses ntlmv2 so I think that's the problem. Deleting the key or changing the value to 3 should help but it might be set via a GPO and for good reasons.